# jQuery form not displaying right in Chrome and Firefox for some reason

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I need help trying to get my form located here to work in Chrome and Firefox please. It works just fine in IE, but the formatting is thrown off in the other two browsers. Thanks everyone.

http://ratzlaffcis4026.x10.mx/Week5/Assignment6/Form4.html

By the way, this form is temporary and will be deleted by this hosting service, eventually. So, this being the case, it's probably not a good resource for some due to this because of x10hosting's policy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `em` instead of `px` for your measurements, as `em` scales with display size etc.

For further reading, [Kyle Schaffer's explanation](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) of the different units is pretty good.

Comment: oh alright. I will try that. Thanks mjc, appreciate it man.

Comment: Wow, this is a really belated response, sorry. That actually did work for me, thanks man